# Can't attach a message for transaction in Waves bitcoin by package @waves/waves-transactions

Tags: attachment

I try to create transaction on Testnet Waves blockchain with short message, I use attachment as a string according to documentation, but I receive a error, that attachment is Object. I see in result of "transfer" function that attachment is not a string it is object: `{ type: 'string', value: '2XTb5rrCf5d1zJkj2jZGjQaA4NPV' }`, but I can't do anything with that, and in the end i have the same error.

P.s.: without attachment this part of code is work fine.

```
const { transfer, broadcast } = require("@waves/waves-transactions");
const nodeUrl = "https://nodes-testnet.wavesnodes.com";
const privateKey =  "...realPrivateKey...";
const signedTranserTx = transfer(
    {
        amount: 1,
        recipient: "3MqfoN68Gj3Eqc9C7pHLqbYvd5k2hovSkgi",
        attachment: "2XTb5rrCf5d1zJkj2jZGjQaA4NPV"
    }
    , {privateKey: privateKey}
);

broadcast( signedTranserTx, nodeUrl)
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Output of signedTranserTx =

```
 {
  type: 4,
  version: 3,
  senderPublicKey: 'He58mC5hQHjQtx6sKcq7MVaeTc6Je9wJthp2P8m7fUXU',
  assetId: null,
  recipient: '3MqfoN68Gj3Eqc9C7pHLqbYvd5k2hovSkgi',
  amount: 1,
  **attachment: { type: 'string', value: '2XTb5rrCf5d1zJkj2jZGjQaA4NPV' },**
  fee: 100000,
  feeAssetId: null,
  timestamp: 1602355529316,
  proofs: [
    'fLmLYr2D1YMLogLtne4NW4YUiB6GufqsfmEjWGqeGS7R56DrB9mXGYDsfQngMGV3EPDwgsh5zNgiv971KezF5AG'
  ],
  chainId: 84,
  id: 'Hw55x7FTuYsPUtuczrdRaJ2kqDCVUgxPuoxndajmeC3C'
}
```

Error request:

```
{
  error: 1,
  message: 'failed to parse json message',
  cause: null,
  validationErrors: { 'obj.attachment': [ [Object] ] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i add type and version attribute to transaction, but change version of transaction from 3 to 2 and now its work. But i didn`t find any information about in documentation.

```
const signedTranserTx = transfer(
    {
        type: 4,
        version: 2,
        amount: 10000,
        recipient: "3MqfoN68Gj3Eqc9C7pHLqbYvd5k2hovSkgi",
        attachment: codedAttachment
    }
    , {privateKey: privateKey}
);
```